# Creating a great color palette

Tags: website-design, color, print-design

For a design assignment, I'm looking for a color that goes nicely with #a31366. The problem is that it's a kind of purple/pink that I've never worked with, so I am bummed out at finding what the best color is.

[image: The color]

I know of Adobe Kuler, but the suggestions it comes up with based on #a31366 are not really what I'm looking for; they seem too childish.

[image: Adobe Kuler suggestion]

What are the tools you use to create a nice color palette? Do you just look at the color swatch in (for example) Photoshop and choose a few that probably fit together? Do you use any tools (like Adobe Kuler)?

Comment: Hi Rvervuurt, unfortunately I think all answers to this question would be *entirely* opinion-based and therefore off-topic.

Comment: That could be so, but I'll take any answer in consideration. I get why this might be the wrong place to ask it though, because I can't mark anything as the "correct" answer.

Comment: Exactly, there would never be a "correct" answer so it's off-topic.

Comment: Maybe the question/answers could be more about the method for creating good color palettes instead? That might make it a bit less opinion based. Maybe more towards: How to get different color options that go well with the other colors...

Comment: Yes, I'll adapt my question @Joonas